# Turning pennies in to change

Tags: java

I'm currently starting to learn Java and am making code that turns pennies in to change. I have completed it however one small problem that I am having is that when I enter 1p or over 501p, it will display the correct message but still carry out the calculation below the message.

I would also appreciate if any other problems could be pointed out :)

My code is:

```
class Main { 
public static void main( String args[] ) {

    System.out.print("#Please enter the amount of change : ");
    int change = BIO.getInt();

    while(change > 0)
    {
        int twopounds, pounds, fifty, twenty, ten, five, two, one;

        twopounds = change / 200;
        int left = change % 200;

        pounds = left / 100;
        left = left % 100;

        fifty = left / 50;
        left = left % 50;

        twenty = left / 20;
        left = left % 20;

        ten = left / 10;
        left = left % 10;

        five = left / 5;
        left = left % 5;

        two = left / 2;
        left = left % 2;

        one = left / 1;

        int nbCoins = twopounds + pounds + fifty + twenty + ten + five + two + one;

        if (change == 1)
        {
            System.out.print("1 coin" + "\n");
        }

        if (change > 500)
        { 
            System.out.print("Invalid amount " + change + "p" + "\n");
        }

        if (change <= 500 && change > 1)

            System.out.print(change + "p " + nbCoins +" coins ");

        {

            if ( twopounds > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( twopounds > 1 ? twopounds + "*200p " : "200p " );
            }

            if ( pounds > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( pounds > 1 ? pounds + "*100p " : "100p " );
            }

            if ( fifty > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( fifty > 1 ? fifty + "*50p " : "50p " );
            }

            if ( twenty > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( twenty > 1 ? twenty + "*20p " : "20p " );
            }

            if ( ten > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( ten > 1 ? ten + "*10p " : "10p " );
            }

            if ( five > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( five > 1 ? five + "*5p " : "5p " );
            }

            if ( two > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( two > 1 ? two + "*2p " : "2p " );
            }

            if ( one > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( one > 1 ? one + "*1p " : "1p " );
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print("#Please enter the amount of change : ");
        change = BIO.getInt();
    }

}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the print after `if (change <= 500 && change > 1)` is in the right place? Should it be in the "curlies"`{}` ?

Comment: If you don't want that message at the bottom, then why did you include it? It is always printed because you told it to.

Comment: I do want it, but only if it's between 2 and 500

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your "if" statement:

```
if (change <= 500 && change > 1)

        System.out.print(change + "p " + nbCoins +" coins ");
```

Only includes the first "print".  It looks like you intended to keep the rest of the if statements within that if, since surrounded them with `{` and `}`.

If you move the `System.out.print(change + "p " + nbCoins +" coins ");` onto the line following the `{` (basically two lines down), then the whole thing should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

An if statement doesn't require curly braces if it only has one statement in it. So where you have your last if statement:

```
if (change <= 500 && change > 1)

    System.out.print(change + "p " + nbCoins +" coins ");

{
    //your other if statements
}
```

The if is basically changed to this:

```
if (change <= 500 && change > 1)
{
    System.out.print(change + "p " + nbCoins +" coins ");
}
```

and the rest of the ifs in the curly braces, are executed out of scope of the main function:

```
{
    if ( twopounds > 0 )
    {
        System.out.print( twopounds > 1 ? twopounds + "*200p " : "200p " );
    }

    if ( pounds > 0 )
    {
        System.out.print( pounds > 1 ? pounds + "*100p " : "100p " );
    }

    //Rest of your ifs
}
```

By out of scope I mean like main doesn't have access to variables created in functions. If you created a new variable in those curly braces, main wouldn't be able to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems unnessecary as it is currently. You can remove a lot of your (repetetive) code by using a loop though along the lines of

```
int[] change = {200, 100, ... , 2, 1};
int changeDue = BIO.getInt();
String changeGiven = "";

for (int i = 0; i < change.length(); arr++)
{
    int n = arr[i];
    int k = changeDue / n;

    changeGiven += String.format(
        "%s%s%i%s\n",
        (n / 100 >= 1 ? "£" : ""), 
        (k > 1 ? k + "*" : ""),
        (n / 100 >= 1 ? n / 100 : n),
        (n / 100 < 1 ? "p" : "")
    );          
}

System.out.println(changeGiven);
```